# How to connect to GUI Environment on CentOS 6 from Windows 7?

Tags: centos, software-installation, gui

I installed a GUI Environment on CentOS 6 server by following [this page](https://www.vultr.com/docs/install-gui-environment-on-centos-6).

I have finished Step 8.

Now how can I connect to the GUI Environment on remote CentOS 6 ?

Do I need use VNC Viewer in my Windows 7 to connect?

Answer (score 0):

Trying using Windows X-server software such as [Cygwin/X](https://x.cygwin.com/), which will allow you to connect to your Centos 6  computer in such a way that GUI application on linux will be displayed locally on your windows computer.

A VNC is slightly separate software. You would first need to setup a **VNC server** on the Centos 6 computer, and then install and connect to it with a **VNC Client** on windows. There are dozens of VNC server/clients out there, a Google search will reveal many. You will have to find one that work with the combination of OS-es you want to use.